# Convert view into high quality image

Tags: android, image, canvas, bitmap

i converted a view into image using this

```
 Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(),
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        view.draw(canvas);
```

this bitmap image is not good quality and distorted, i want high quality image.
please tell me how to make high quality image of a view in Android.

i want image like this

[image]

but this which i am getting is distorted

[image]

Comment: What do you mean not high quality? Can you add the image you're getting when you run this code and the expected image you want via a screenshot of the device? This is the recommended way of quickly copying the exact contents of a View.

Comment: @WadeWilson images added

Comment: can you try this `Bitmap.Config.RGBA_F16` instead of `Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888`.?

Comment: Interesting, I've never seen that happen before. Try checking the height and width of the view and make sure they are correct size. Maybe it's a scaling issue (though I doubt). Try this method of getting a screenshot.: First enable drawing cache by calling view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true), then call the method view.getDrawingCache() to get the bitmap of the view.
   return

Comment: @WadeWilson i tried it also but result is same

Comment: @AsadMahmood, also try KuLdip PaTel suggestion but note that it is only available for api level 26 and above and it uses significantly more memory. Each pixel is stored using 8 bytes compared to 1 byte. That can easily eat memory and cause an OOM exception. Also it should only be used if you are supporting wide-gamut and HDR content. I don't thing your issue is related to color precision.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.Config.html this need Api 26.

Comment: its not working for me. i want to do that for API level 19 to 23

Comment: @Asad Mahmood The two images you uploaded aren't the exact same aspect ration. i'm not sure if what you're seeing is artifacting do to the change in image scale.